# What happens when doing an upsert and has more than two rows with the same key in the on conflict constraint and we perform an UPDATE SET?

Tags: postgresql, psycopg2

Imagine something like this:

```
INSERT INTO table1
(data_1, data_2, data_3)
VALUES %s
ON CONFLICT (data_2) where active
DO UPDATE SET
    data_1 = EXCLUDED.data_1, 
    data_2 = EXCLUDED.data_2, 
    data_3 = EXCLUDED.data_3,
```

What happens when there is a conflict of more than two rows with the same `data_2` key?

Will the query will update the two or more rows with the `do update set` that has a conflict on them, or it will throw an error?

Comment: Why not create example rows to check what happens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [doc](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-insert.html#SQL-ON-CONFLICT) says

> INSERT with an ON CONFLICT DO UPDATE clause is a “deterministic”
> statement. This means that the command will not be allowed to affect
> any single existing row more than once; a cardinality violation error
> will be raised when this situation arises. Rows proposed for insertion
> should not duplicate each other in terms of attributes constrained by
> an arbiter index or constraint.

So if you have a conflict on `data2` on more than two rows, it will throw an error